# Update info asking origin and destination records in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Seems that This will be an easy question for you but this problem is meltin my head for almost 1 hour !

I have a table (noeuds) with many different equipments (noeud), each of them I have the address as Rivoli, insee_com, num_voie.

I need to copy the address from one noeud to another noeud prompeted by microsoft access user in a simple query. I tried something like this for a simple one, can anyone bring light to my room and help me with this issue?

```
UPDATE noeuds AS n 
SET n.RIVOLI = SELECT RIVOLI FROM noeuds WHERE (NOEUD=[orig])

WHERE (SELECT noeuds.NOEUD, noeuds.* FROM noeuds WHERE (((noeuds.NOEUD)=[dest])));
```

I'm using a M$ Access database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over thinking it. Just reference the noeuds table twice in the UPDATE clause using aliases set destination field = source field and use a simple where

```
UPDATE noeuds AS dest, noeuds AS source 
SET dest.RIVOLI = source.RIVOLI
WHERE 
      dest.NOEUD =[dest]  
      and 
     source.NOEUD  = [orig]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I would change more than 100 records by hand copying addresses for each project. I really needed that simple update refresh....